# Sapper doesnt export *.json.js files

Tags: javascript, json, svelte, vercel, sapper

I am building website where I have a contact form. I user sapper and vercel.
I have a file contact in `/src/kontakt.svelte` where I have the form and I have this piece of script:

```
const sendMail = async () => {
const res = await fetch('/mail.json', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "name": name,
    "email": email,
    "body": body,
    "time": new Date
  })
});
```

}

This communicates with mail.json.js which is in `/src/mail.json.js` that contains:

```
var mailgun = require('mailgun.js');
const forVercel = process.env.mailgun_priv
var mg = mailgun.client({username: 'api', key: 'secret', url: 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net'});

export async function post(req, res, next) {
  const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(req.body.email)
    mg.messages.create('aaa', {
      from: `Excited User <${req.body.email}>`,
      to: ["aaa@gmail.com"],
      subject: "Formulář - aaa",
      html: `<p>Čas: ${req.body.time}</p>
           <br>
           <p>Jméno: ${req.body.name}</p>
           <br>
           <p>Mail: ${req.body.email}</p>
           <br>
           <p>Obsah: ${req.body.body}</p>`
    })
      .then(msg => console.log(msg)) // logs response data
      .catch(err => console.log(err)); // logs any error
  })
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

When I run the project locally with `sapper dev` it works flawlessly.
But when I deploy it to vercel or run `sapper export` and run it. There is A ERROR of:

```
POST https://website.com/mail.json 
404 Not Found
```

It seems that sapper doesnt process the mail.json.js file.

Comment: You need to share a minimal reproducible example. It is not possible to debug this issue as it was currently presented.

Comment: @paulogdm I hava made a github repo just for this issue https://github.com/Lumca/my-app

Comment: Your server route in Sapper is implemented as a Node / Express server. Vercel won't deploy that by default, only a static export of the client. AFAIK you can deploy server routes as lambdas (meaning you won't have a long running Node server like you have in dev). Judging by the code you've shown, it seems possible that it could be converted to a lambda, but it will need special configuration in Vercel, and special code in your project.